# deducing matrix square root from inverse function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

This is a problem from Ted Shifrin's book on Mutivariable Mathematics, *I have asked a similar question earlier, but as I am revisiting this problem after 3 years, I realized my old question and answer do not provide a satisfactory or comprehensive answer*.

Given $\mathbf{f}: A \mapsto A^2$, for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

(a) Applying the Inverse Function Theorem, show that  every matrix $B$ in a neighbourhood of $I$ has (atleast) 2 square roots $A$, that is $A^2 = B$, each varying as a $C^1$ function of $B$.

(b) Can you decide if there are precisely 2 or more ? (Hint: in  2x2 case, what is $D\mathbf{f}\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
                                           0  & -1 \end{bmatrix} \right )$ ?

---

I am able to solve part (a) by observing that $f(\pm I) = I$, so the inverse function theorem  can be applied to the map $\mathbf{f}$ at $A =I$ and $A= -I$. Thus  it asserts the existence of  inverse functions $\phi_1, \phi_2$ so that, two square roots are accounted for, and I have shown that there exist  *at least* 2 square roots.

---

My question pertains to part  (b).

I can see that Inverse function theorem does not apply, since  the map $D\mathbf{f}\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
                                           0  & -1 \end{bmatrix} \right )$ is not invertible.

However,  $ f\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
                                           0  & -1 \end{bmatrix} \right ) = I $.

Since the map $f$ is continuous, for a given $\epsilon > 0$, one can find $\delta > 0$ so that $X \in \delta-$neighbourhood of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
                                           0  & -1 \end{bmatrix}$
will be mapped by $f$ to $\epsilon-$neighbourhood of $I$.

Thus there exist $B$ near $I$ that have distinct pre-images (square roots) in the neighbourhoods of $I, -I, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
                                           0  & -1 \end{bmatrix}$.

At this point, I can only conclude that

1) I can construct a neighbourhood aroundn $I$ wherein every $B$ has 2 square roots

2) For some $B$, there might be a third square root.

**Q) So how can I definitively answer (b), that is, decide if there are precisely 2 or more square roots for  $B$ in  the neighbourhood of $I$?**

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854603/inverse-function-theorem-and-matrix-square-root?rq=1) can help you.

Comment: @ManojKumar: I am aware of that, I was the one who posted that question 3 years ago,  and I say so in this post too. The explanations there do not answer my question completely.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, any reflection (across a line in $\Bbb R^2$ or across any nontrivial subspace in higher dimensions) gives a square root of $I$. The matrix $A_0=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ gives an example, of course. $D\mathbf f(A_0)$ has a $2$-dimensional nullspace, accounting for varying the $\pm 1$-eigenspaces of the reflection. However, as was already pointed out in the answer to your first question, there are matrices arbitrarily close to $I$ (e.g., $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \epsilon \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$) having no square root near $A_0$ (or, indeed, any other reflection matrix). So $\mathbf f$ is a local diffeomorphism, as expected, only at $\pm I$, not at any other preimages of $I$.

Comment: When you ask in (b): "Are there 2 or more", are you referring to inverse functions defined in a neighbourhood, or are you asking if any $B$ near $I$ has more than 2 square roots ? Because, unless I have a mistake in my analysis above, I do show in my answer that there will be some elements near $I$ that do have 3 pre-images, i.e., square roots.

Comment: I meant to ask whether every matrix in *some* neighborhood of $I$ could have more than $2$. As I've already argued above, $I$ has infinitely many preimages, and we can follow directions *not* in the nullspace of the derivative at such points to get nearby matrices with square roots near $A_0$. I haven't thought about what happens if we take $A_0$ and $A'_0$ very close and look at matrices near each of them with square roots. Will those two-parameter loci intersect or not? That would be interesting for you to work out.