# apply the Inverse Function Theorem to matrices

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

Define $f(A) = A^2$ where A is a $n\times n$ matrix.
(a) Show that every matrix $B$ in a neighbourhood of the identity matrix $I$ has at least 2 square roots, that is, each varying as a $C^1$ function of $B$. 
(b) Are there exactly 2 or more? (Hint: think about $Df\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
                                           0  & -1 \end{bmatrix} \right )$

I know this problem has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854603/inverse-function-theorem-and-matrix-square-root?rq=1) but I can't understand the answer that was given there.

I know that we have to apply the inverse function theorem, and for the inverse function theorem to be applicable, the determinant of $Df(I)$ has to be zero. But I don't know what does $Df(I)$ look like and now I'm stuck.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain what exactly it is that you don't understand from the answer. Do you understand, for instance, what is meant by
$$
Df_A(H) = AH + HA?
$$

Comment: I don’t know what does $diag$ means, and I also don’t know what $P$ and $Q$ stands for in the first part of the answer. As for $Df_A(H)$, my understanding is that the derivative of $f$ at $A$ applied to $H$ is $AH+HA$. But I don’t know how do we get the equation.

Comment: I think I just figured it out. Since $Df(I)(H)=IH+HI=2H$, $DF(I)$ is a linear map that sends a matrix $H$ to $2H$, so we can probably write $Df(I)=2I$ and thus the determinant of it is nonzero. Am I right?

Comment: That is a valid approach. A simpler approach is to note that the map $Df(I)$ is invertible since we can define its inverse $Df(I)^{-1}(H) = \frac 12 H$. Thus, the determinant of this linear map is non-zero